# Copy newest file in directory over SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, quoting

**How might one copy the newest text file from a particular directory on a remote server to his local machine?**

On the server itself I can do the following:

```
$ cat `cd /home/user/dir ; readlink -f $(ls -t | head -1)` > ~/newest.txt
```

This puts the content of the newest file into `~/newest.txt`. However, I cannot run this over SSH because the local system tries to interpret the tick marks and `$(*)` commands. Id est, this does not work:

```
$ ssh me@server.com "cat `cd /home/user/dir ; readlink -f $(ls -t | head -1)`" > ~/newest.txt
bash: cd: /home/user/dir: No such file or directory
Connection to server.com closed.
```

Obviously, `/home/user/dir` does not exist on *my local machine*. I tried using SSH with the `-t` flag as well, this did not help. **How can I get the ticks and `$()` to be parsed on the remote machine, not on my local machine?**

As an aside, somebody smarter than me once declared that [the output of `ls` shall not be parsed](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). We can safely assume for purposes of this question that the filenames contain only printable ASCII characters. However, answers which address the general case would be great as well as I do want to *learn*, not just get by this once.

Comment: Hi! First, please use code tag around your **ssh** commands starting from `$` until the end of the line because they are printed wrong now - backticks are not displayed. I tried to edit your post but a single edit must be more than 8 characters and I couldn't do it.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: Thanks, sorry about that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use single quotes instead of double quotes to prevent shell expansion before your command is passed to a remote server.

BTW, `$(` are now preferred over `` ` `` in command substitution. Unless you use shell that only supports `` ` `` consider using `$(` in command substitution. See [here for more details](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).