# How does a terminal emulator work

Tags: terminal

I never really understood how a terminal emulator (be it e.g. XTerm or the Linux virtual console) works. What transformations happen to the input (key up/down events) to produce the output (usually the standard input of the application that is running in the terminal, a signal being sent and so on)? What is actually the input for the terminal and what is already handled by the input drivers (in the kernel, X server, ...). How and where do the terminal capabilities databases like terminfo or termcap enter this process? How are "special" keys like arrows processed? And conversely: how does it work the other way round: application standard output/error → medium (screen, paper)?

Comment: some answers [there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120071/22565). You might want to break this down into several questions. Otherwise it's going to be too broad.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say exactly "broad" but definitely "long". I'll read your answer on the other question thoroughly and will try to refactor this question into several (linked) parts tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas actually your answer in the other question provided me with an important search term: *line discipline*. I'll have to read about that a bit more to make sure what pieces of the puzzle will be still missing.

Comment: http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/

Comment: I'm voting to close as a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work which presents a high-level view. Together with [Stéphane's excellent detailed answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117981/what-are-the-responsibilities-of-each-pseudo-terminal-pty-component-software/120071#120071), I think this provides as good a presentation of what you're asking here as it gets. You're welcome to edit your question if there are points that you feel are missing.

Comment: More [there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151963/22565) on line disciplines.

Comment: @Gilles I'm perfectly fine with that. I'll probably ask for reopening once I get through all the referenced sources - even if just to create an answer that would gather it all in one place with a little bit of glue. Thanks.