# Unexpected indentation behaviour when I set the terminal to raw mode – why is this happening?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

Based on what I have read, when a terminal is in raw mode, the characters are not processed by the terminal driver, but are sent straight through.

I set the terminal in raw mode using the command `stty raw`, and I noticed that the output is indented to the right each time until there is no more room. This is what I mean:

[image]

Why is this behavior happening?!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

One of the [`stty`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stty&sektion=1) settings (**`onlcr`**) tells the *terminal driver* to convert *newline* (which is actually ASCII line-feed) to carriage-return plus line-feed.

Unix-like systems just write a *newline* to end lines, letting the terminal driver do the right thing (convert *newline* to carriage-return plus line-feed).

Carriage-return "goes left" and line-feed "goes down".

When you set the terminal to raw mode, *newline* will no longer be converted to carriage-return plus line-feed. Lacking the carriage-returns, you get that *staircase* effect.

Comment: and for a in-depth view, you can have a look at @stéphane-chazelas really good post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151916/why-is-this-binary-file-transfered-over-ssh-t-being-changed/151963#151963 , which shows a lot of interresting things about terminal conversions (and their side effects). In a nutshell: only "ssh -t" to use interactive commands, but in your scripts use just ssh if you want to get the exact thing the command generated (ex:   tar files created on one side of an ssh and read/written on the other side: don't add "-t" or it could (...will?) mess up your binaries )