# Confused about the "onlcr" stty flag

Tags: linux, stty

In the `stty` [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stty), the following is mentioned:

> [-]icrnl
>       translate carriage return to newline
>
> [-]inlcr
>       translate newline to carriage return
>
> * [-]ocrnl
>       translate carriage return to newline
>
> * [-]onlcr
>       translate newline to carriage return-newline

Notice how the "cr" in `icrnl` and `inlcr` and `ocrnl` mean "carriage return" but it means "carriage return-newline" in `onlcr`.

Is this a typo, or is this how `onlcr` really works (i.e. 
it translates `\n` to `\r\n`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a typo, it is in fact what [POSIX also says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/stty.html):

> onlcr  (-onlcr)
>
> Map (do not map) NL to CR-NL on output. This shall have the effect of setting (not setting) ONLCR in the termios c_oflag field, as defined in XBD General Terminal Interface.

The fact that the mode isn't called "onlcrnl" is probably just to keep the setting names short and consistent (or at least consistently short).

The Rationale section tells us that the standard for `stty` was adopted from System V, so I'm assuming there was backward compatibility to older systems to care about too.

Comment: [And you do want the nl to be translated to crnl so that the terminal takes the cursor back to the beginning of the line (cr) and one line down (nl)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151963)

Comment: The termio flag was already called ONLCR in System III in 1980

Comment: Before that (and starting Unix V3 I beleive), `stty -nl` (`CRMOD` flag in `sgtty.h`) would have been the equivalent of today's `stty icrnl onlcr`