# What causes \r's to be inserted before \n's when retrieving a binary file over ssh, and how do I circumvent it?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sudo, restore, dump

I have inherited a Ubuntu 14.04 production server which needs to be upgraded to 20.04, and I would like a sandboxed version to experiment with first, hence I want to `dump` and `restore` the filesystems over the network from either a MacOS or another 14.04 virtualbox instance.  An earlier version of this question is at https://askubuntu.com/q/1314747/963.

The server cannot "see" my machines so I cannot easily run dump and push the result remotely to my machine, but need to invoke ssh from my machine to run dump.

```
ssh -t me@there "echo MYPASSWORD | sudo -S dump -y -f - /boot 2>/dev/null " > boot.dump
```

Problem is that I've found that running this command inserts a lot of `\r` characters in front of `\n` characters which ruins the dump file so `restore` cannot use it.  I understand that this is probably due to a driver translating linefeeds to the characters needed for printing, but I do not see where this is triggered.

How should I do this to get the correct binary dump file?

Comment: Drop the `-t` from `ssh`.

Comment: @user414777 I found the -t to be necessary to allow me to pass in the password to sudo.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen if you're sufficiently privileged (well, you can `sudo`, so you probably are), it might be easier to configure sudo with `!requiretty` and `NOPASSWD`?

Comment: Rather than ssh and echo your password to `sudo` on the other machine ( which exposed your password to other users on the machine who can run `ps` ), you might have an easier time adding your ssh key to /root/.ssh/authorized_keys on the remote machine and sshing in directly as root.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is this binary file transferred over "ssh -t" being changed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151916/why-is-this-binary-file-transferred-over-ssh-t-being-changed)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's the `ONLCR` `.c_oflag` termios setting which is causing the newline (`\n`) to be turned into carriage-return/newline (`\r\n`) by the pseudo-terminal allocated by `ssh` on the remote machine (because of ssh's `-t` option).

Turn it off with `stty -onlcr`:

```
ssh -t me@there 'stty -onlcr; ...' > output
```

Comment: Thank you.  Trying this with the /boot partition resulted in a file liked by `restore t` so is very promising.

Answer (score 2):

The official ASCII line ending is `CR LF` (i.e., return to line start and go to next line, `\r\n` in C-ish). To shave off a byte for each line (very important when yor memory is measured in KiB and disks are a few hundred MiB), Unix just uses `\n` to mark line end. Some systems (notably Microsoft) *did* go with the standard, so when moving text files among systems you have sometimes a translation task at hand.

Comment: Thank you.  I understand the mechanism and the history behind it (seen it since the CP/M days) but not how it applied in my scenario.

Comment: @vonbrand ASCII defines the control characters Carriage Return and Line Feed. Unix *does* use these when talking to a device that requires them. However, internally Unix uses a newline character a a separator between lines in files and in memory. The Line Feed character was chosen for this, because one is enough. Internally, Unix handles line breaks at a higher level of abstraction than the characters controlling the movement of a mechanical print head.

Comment: Not the "ASCII" line ending, the "Internet" one.

Comment: *The official ASCII line ending is CR LF* But this is just false.  LF is also known as "newline", and its use as a single-character line ending is well established.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline, in particular the History section.